# ASP.Net MVC 2 Error Method not found: 'System .string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I converted my website from asp.net mvc 1.0 to 2.0. After converting that i am getting the following error in actionlink

```
Method not found: 'System.String System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.RouteLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)'.

Line 102:                    <%var Signin = Html.Resource("globalResources, Signin"); %>
Line 103:                    <% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Signin)) Signin = "Signin"; %>
Line 104:                    <%= Html.ActionLink<AccountController>(cntrl => cntrl.LogOn(), Signin.ToString(), new { @class = "defaultmaster" })%>
Line 105:                    |
Line 106:                    <%var register = Html.Resource("globalResources, Register"); %>


Source File: e:\Muchsocial\Sourcecode\Muchsocial\Views\Shared\Muchsocial.Master    Line: 104
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using MvcFutures from version 1.0 still?  You might want to upgrade and use MvcFutures from 2.0.

Comment: I already upgrade and then its not working. It was working in Version 1.0